# Set up Port Triggering on a Netcomm NF4V router not working

Tags: router, vpn

I'm trying to set up port triggering on my Netcomm NF4V router to allow access to a VPN but it's not working.

The instructions I'm following are [here.](http://media.netcomm.com.au/public/assets/file/0020/136505/NF4V-Port-Triggering-Setup-Guide_opt.pdf)

I get to the setup page but there's nothing in the Use Interface box - so I can't select the interface which I suspect is preventing this from working. (I enter the port configuration and click Save/Apply but it does nothing.)

Here's a screenshot of what I see:

[image]

How do I set the interface up so that it appears in the drop-down box?

Comment: Have you tried a different browser/ disabling browser extensions ...?

Comment: Yes - no other browser makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Getting my ISP to update my router to the latest firmware (R5R032) solved the problem.